# An issue with large map for Tamriel Rebuilt mod

Tags: mods, the-elder-scrolls-iii-morrowind

I'm playing with Tamriel Rebuilt installed and I am using [Morrowind Code Patch](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Tes3Mod:Morrowind_Code_Patch) to get 
map expansion so that the whole map is visible, for some of my savegames there seems to be a problem when the two old and the new maps overlap like this:[image].
It seems that the original map is on top of the MCP map. This is the issue only with some savegame files, for others it works as intended, is there any way to fix this? For Oblivion there were some utilities which could update savegame files, are there similar tools for Morrowind?

Answer (score 2):

As the Morrowind Code Patch tells you when you change this option, you need to use the "Update Map" function of [Wrye Mash](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Tes3Mod:Wrye_Mash) (Morrowind's version of Wrye Bash) to have the correct map on a game saved before changing.