# How do I update a morrowind map using Wyre Mash?

Tags: pc, mods, the-elder-scrolls-iii-morrowind

I am having problems with the mod "Tamriel Rebuilt", so I uninstalled it. However the large map is having a conflict, the original map is trying to overlap the new map that came with "Tamriel Rebuilt" and "Morrowind Code Patch". people say that the Wyre Mash (A Morrowind data manager in a sense) can update the map and fix the problem, if you don't know what I mean take a look at this:

[An issue with large map for Tamriel Rebuilt mod](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/70375/an-issue-with-large-map-for-tamriel-rebuilt-mod)

He says to update the map but I can't find out how to do that anywhere, can you please help me?.

Comment: It sounds like you need to merge the two mods using Wrye Mash, but I haven't done that in years. Here's a WM instruction manual - http://wryemusings.com/Wrye%20Mash.html and you can also post something in the Morrowind Mods section of the Bethesda Forums. There's still a large modding community there on the forums.

Comment: I tried merging mods, it said there was nothing to merge, I'll try again. thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You need to open Wrye Mash and go to the "Saves" tab. From there right click on your save file(s) and the option to update map will be on the bottom of the right click menu.